# How can you open a saved .py file in idle3 without it defaulting to normal text?

Tags: python, python-idle

I recently started using idle3 to follow along with some course material as recommended by the instructor. Opening a new shell and running python code works just fine, the problem is when i save the file and later try to reopen it to continue on with the course work.

When ever i open the designated .py file, it only loads up in regular text, i can no longer execute new code, the line break doesn't have the ">>>" before each line, it won't even give any output

How can i open a saved file and continue on implementing code?

Comment: the default of idle is open the in text editor mode when you open a .py file, to execute the file press F5 or go to the `Run` menu a select `Run Module`

Comment: "invalid syntax" is the response I get when i do that

Comment: if you saved file have `>>>` all over the place, is not going to work as that is not proper python code, otherwise the problem is, well, an invalid syntax somewhere...

Comment: it does have >>> all over the place but is there no way to get the console up and running once again back to its previous state?  why would it include >>> in every new shell if it can't read it once you save the file and try to reopen it?

Comment: you make a new file in the file menu, write there all the code you want, like functions classes or whatever else, save and run it as previously mention, now the in new or previous idle console (sometime open a new one other not) you can run all the functions or whatever else you written to the file, but anything that you write in the interactive console will stay there, any change you want to make to your functions on the file you need to do it in the file in the text editor mode and run it again

Comment: It is a buglet that saved shell sessions get the .py extension.  The intention was that one could load such into an editor and edit or comment out the non-code parts, leaving the code parts to be run.  But sometimes people get understandably  confused.  I am not quite sure yet what changes to make.

Answer (score 0):

The basic use of the IDLE is for 2 thing, text editor and interactive console.

The interactive console allow you to write any python code and see it running immediately, great quick calculation and/or testing code until you get the desired result.

The save option (File -> Save) is deceptive however, because it save everything as you see including the `>>>` so saving as .py just doesn't work, or not without some extra work, namely removing all the `>>>` and all other undesired stuff, so is more like screenshot of sort.

The text editor mode is, well, just that but specialized for python with its syntax highlight and whatnot, use it to write your modules or whatever else, save it as .py and run the code by pressing F5 in order to test it, which will open a new interactive console with all that code loaded into it or would load it into a previously open one in which case it will reset it first, and that means that anything not in the file will be discarded (but you can scroll up can copy-pasted again if needed)

So for example, in a file you have

```
def greetings(name):
    print("hello",name)
```

and you open it with the text editor mode of IDLE, simply run (F5) and you now have access to that function in the interactive console

```
>>> greetings("bob")
hello bob
>>> a=23
>>>
```

and lets make a new variable with some value

Now lets said we go back to the file and add some more stuff and now it looks like

```
def greetings(name):
    print("hello",name)

def add(a,b):
    return a+b

b=42
```

and run it again, this reset the console, which is indicated a msj like this containing the path of the loaded file

```
====== RESTART: C:\Users\Copperfield\Documents\StackOverflow\example.py =====
>>>
```

now we have the `greetings` and `add` function but the variable `a` from before is now loss

```
>>> a
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<pyshell#6>", line 1, in <module>
    a
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
>>>
```

but you have `b`

```
>>> b
42
>>>
```

---

So, use the text editor mode to write all the stuff you want to keep and in the interactive console play with it to test that is indeed the thing you want, and if not just go and edit it some more...